# Using Proguard in Gradle - can't find referenced class java.lang.String

Tags: java, gradle, proguard

I'm trying to configure ProGuard as part of my Gradle build scripts for a java application in Ubuntu, accessed through bash, but I can't seem to get it right.  I've never used either technology before.  Using the [ProGuard Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/gradle.html) I wrote the following task, which I currently call on a pre-existing jar file while I try and get something working.

```
task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
  injars         'build/libs/myapplication.jar'
  outjars        'build/libs/myapplication_out.jar'
  libraryjars    '<java.home>/lib/rt.jar'
  printmapping   'myapplication.map'

  keep 'public class mypackage.MyMainClass {  \
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);  \
  }'
}
```

I get back a lot of lines stating missing built in java library files such as:

```
Warning: myclasses: can't find referenced class java.lang.String
```

At the bottom of the list I also see:

```
Could not call ProGuardTask.proguard()
```

If I check my output directory, I can see it created the directory structure but not the jar file and this is what I see if I run my gradle task with stacktrace on:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not call ProGuardTask.proguard() on task
```

I had a look on the proguard trouble shooting page and it said that I should make sure I'm specifying the run-time library of my platform and that for JSE this is lib/rt.jar.  You can see that up there in the library jars argument.  What have I missunderstood?

Comment: First thing to figure out is if `Could not call ProGuardTask.proguard()` comes from Gradle or ProGuard. Perhaps show the full stack trace. `can't find referenced class java.lang.String` sounds like ProGuard isn't being configured correctly.

Answer (score 11):

ProGuard is not reading the runtime jar, because its name should be specified differently.

In ProGuard configuration files, you can write:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

In Gradle build files, you should use Gradle's style:

```
libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
```

Comment: Do you know where to find rt.jar or an equivalent with JDK 10? It doesn't seem to come with the JDK anymore

Comment: @MariusVolkhart rt.jar was removed since jdk 9

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to setup my classpath for my gradle proguard task.  Used a copy task to gather all the jar files in play and then referenced them in the proguard task.

```
task prepare(type: Copy) {

    dependsOn 'jar'

    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/assemble/izpack")
    includeEmptyDirs = true

    into('lib') {
        from configurations.compile
    }
    into('proguard') {
        from configurations.runtime {  include '*truelicense*.jar' }
    }
}


task proguard (type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {

    dependsOn 'prepare'

    configuration "proguard.conf"

    injars jar.archivePath
    fileTree("$buildDir/assemble/izpack/proguard").include("*.jar").each { f ->
        injars f.path, filter: '!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }

    outjars "$buildDir/assemble/izpack/web/WEB-INF/lib/${jar.baseName}-${jar.version}.${jar.extension}"

    libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
    libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/jce.jar"
    fileTree("$buildDir/assemble/izpack/lib").include("**/*.jar").collect { f -> libraryjars f.path }
    fileTree("$buildDir/assemble/izpack/web").include("**/*.jar").collect { f -> libraryjars f.path }
}
```